# WebClient and HttpAsyncClients using repeatable request

Tags: java, post, webclient

I'm implementing a post call with `WebClient` on a service that uses NTLM authentication. In past I had no problem using `RestTemplate` to authenticate with this mechanism, but using `WebClient` I'm stuck since I receive the authentication challenge but can't complete since I have a non repeatable request.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
    credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(properties.getHostName(),
            properties.getPort()), 
            new NTCredentials(properties.getUser(),
                    properties.getPassword().toCharArray(),
                    properties.getSource(), 
                    properties.getDomain()));

    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {

        log.debug("set credentials as: {}, {}, {}, {} on host:port : {}:{}", properties.getUser(), properties.getPassword(),
                properties.getSource(), properties.getDomain(), properties.getHostName(), properties.getPort());

    }


    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
            .setAuthenticationEnabled(true)
            .setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(Collections.singletonList(StandardAuthScheme.NTLM))
            .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
            .setRedirectsEnabled(true)
            .setResponseTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(Long.valueOf(properties.getTimeout())))
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(Long.valueOf(properties.getReadTimeout())))
            .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(true)
            .setConnectionKeepAlive(TimeValue.ofMilliseconds(properties.getTimeout()))
            .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector
            (HttpAsyncClients
                    .custom()
                    .setRetryStrategy(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryStrategy(3, TimeValue.ofMilliseconds(50)))
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                    .setTargetAuthenticationStrategy(DefaultAuthenticationStrategy.INSTANCE)
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                    .build());

    WebClient.builder()
            .codecs(configurer -> 
            configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(properties.getMaxBufferSize() > 0 
                    ? properties.getMaxBufferSize() : 50 * 1024 * 1024))
            .clientConnector(httpConnector).build();
    Map<String, Object> resp = webClient.post()
    .uri(uri)
    .body(Mono.just(payload), Input.class)
    .cookies(cookies -> cookies.addAll(cookiesToSet))
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Map.class)
    .cache()
    .block();
```

I've tried using .retry and .repeat, but it still fails since it's a non repeatable request,  so my question is, how can I implement a repeatable request to engaeg the ntlm Authentication correctly?